# Local Database Cache: "Post-Only" and Foreign Keys

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, caching

First off: we are using Visual Studio 2010, .Net 4 and SQL Server 2008 R2 (and C#)

We currently are migrating an old application to .Net. In fact, it's a full re-write.

The application will be a server-client setup and fully fits the "occasionally connected" description.

A typical installation involves 10 clients and one server. The clients are accessing a pool of semi-static data from the database (let's call this the core-data).

The clients also add a range of new entries each day (about 700 to 800) to another table. let's just call this "postings".

Now we want to have a local database as a cache for two purposes:

1. For our main customer the core-data consists of about 200000 entries and there are about 100 changes each day. We want to cache this data on the clients because we need fast access to it.
2. For several other, smaller customers we do not have dedicated servers running. One of the client machines is doing this job. If the users shut down the "server" the clients won't be able to save the new postings. This actually is an acute problem and happens quite often (untrained users). We need some kind of cache for this.

Now, I read about the local database cache you can add via Visual Studio and I already gave it a try.

In theory, this is exactly what we need. However, in reality I encountered a few difficulties:

1. I noticed that when creating the local cache DB the foreign key relations are missing from the local DB. I saw that this is documented as "working as intended", however I was not able to find an instruction on how to properly include them so I can rely on them in the local DB and I'll still be able to sync.

   After I added the relations myself I still ended up with syncing problems:

   I have two tables, Table A and Table B. I added one entry on table A and 30 entries on table B referencing the entry in table A.

   Upon Syncing table A was synced correctly - on table B no entries were synced.

   I added another 30 entries to table B and tried to sync again. this time it ignored the first 30 entries and tried to only sync the new 30 entries. out of those it only synced one successfully. I am clearly missing something here.
2. A purely theoretical question: The sync can be "Upload Only", "Download Only" etc. What we'd need is something like "Post Only". Because I was not able to get the whole setup working I'll add this question without having tested it myself:

   What will happen if I sync "Upload Only" and clear all entries from the local DB after syncing? Will it delete the entries from the server upon the next sync? If yes, can we still use the Sync Service for this purpose or should we use a DataSet and post the entries manually to the server?